# OpenGL: C++: Buffer quad objects (like cylinders?)

Tags: c++, performance, qt, opengl, buffer

If I would like to draw 5000 cylinders with different positions and orientations using the call

```
  glRotated(x1,y1,z1,theta);
  glTranslatef(x,y,z);

  quadObj = gluNewQuadric ();
  gluQuadricDrawStyle (quadObj, GLU_FILL);
  gluQuadricNormals (quadObj, GLU_SMOOTH);
  gluCylinder(quadObj, D, D, L-4*D, 32, 1);
  gluDeleteQuadric(quadObj);
```

What's the most efficient way to do it?

From what I read I saw that one has to buffer them then send them to the hardware, but I only saw examples for simple objects that consist of vertices like triangles.

Could you provide me with some examples on how to buffer complicated objects?

Comment: If you care about efficiency, then you shouldn't be using the GLU functions. Also, *all* OpenGL objects "consist of vertices".

Comment: @Nicol So you're suggesting that I build all objects from vertices? Is it the way professional OpenGL programmers do it?

Comment: @SamerAfach: Yes, that's exactly what we do. And BTW: GLU does the same. OpenGL has no concept of higher level objects. All it knows are vertices and point, lines or triangles made from them.

Comment: @datenwolf Thank you for the reply. Can you please tell me how you decide the number of samples along the radius of a circle, or a cylinder? As you know, more points need more calculations, and less points make circles/cylinders look kinky.